# What to do when Libxml2 have a basal data type more restrictive than a derived XSD data type?

Tags: php, xsd, libxml2

If a third party (lets say govermment) makes available a XSD, which is less restrictive than Libxml2 about basal datatypes, e.g. [XSD's decimalDerived maxInclusive] > [Libxml2 decimal maxInclusive]. Should in this case just modify the XSD to comply with Libxml2 restrictions or am I missing something?

I do not like the idea of modifying third party XSD, maybe there is some standard method to solve this problem without modifying the XSD. In the other hand, and yet more important, the XSD provided is for interchangable information, I should not restrict received XML, more than what the XSD says.

For example a XSD with the next type:

```
<xs:simpleType name="AmountType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:totalDigits value="100"/>
        <xs:fractionDigits value="20"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="9999999999999999999999999"/><!-- 25 DIGITS -->
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Will cause DOMDocument::schemaValidate() to fail, return false, and throw a warning, even if `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);`. In this case, with `libxml_get_errors();`, the next errors are captured when validating the schema of a XML against the XSD:

Error 1824:

> Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}maxInclusive':
>   '9999999999999999999999999' is not a valid value of the
>   atomic type 'xs:decimal'. in /path/schema.xsd on line X

Error 1717:

> Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}maxInclusive': The value
>   '9999999999999999999999999' of the facet does not validate
>   against the base type '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}decimal'. in
>   /path/schema.xsd on line X

Comment: XML Schema 1.0 documented a minimum number of digits a processor had to support (18). So relying on more while claiming it's schema 1.0 is always going to cause compatibility issues. At first glance, schema 1.1 does not mention any digit limit, but libxml2 only supports 1.0 afaik.

Comment: @Zastai, it is a minimum limit of 18 by XML Schema 1.0, 18+ digits is still 1.0, because there is no maximum limit, just 18 or superior.

Comment: The point is that the standard does not require support for more than 18 digit (it even allows supporting fewer, if that restriction is well-documented). So while the XSD is technically valid, no schema processor is required to support it. And so the XSD will have compatibility issues.

Comment: @Zastai, but what is so complicated about supporting few more digits? after all, XML is just text, which makes me think that there is a way to bypass that limit, by somehow "loosening" the libxml2 validation.

Comment: The problem is supporting things like max/min values - that requires value processing and not just text. A Java-based processor could simply use a BigDecimal (no real limit), and a .Net one could use its decimal type (28 full-range digits); but there's no decimal type in the C library. A 64-bit integer provides 18 full-range digits, so combined with a scale (for the position of the decimal point), it makes supporting 18 digits (relatively) easy. For more than that, the processor would likely need to link with another library (like GMP).